Redis dbinfo returning higher key count than sum of keys in individual slots
We're running a redis cluster(4 masters + 4 replicas, redis_version:6.2.14) with around 300 million keys. We are noticing one of the master/replica pairs having a lot more keys than any other node in the cluster. When all remaining nodes have around 75 million keys, this particular pair hosts 90 million. We also see a corresponding increase in memory usage in this pair.
We are not able to see any discrepancy in the number of slots assigned to this particular node. And counting the total number of keys in the instance by looping over assigned slots and using COUNTKEYSINSLOT returns a value of around 75 million(as opposed to 90 million returned by dbsize). Is there something we could be missing here?

Do you see it constantly in the same pair? Is it constant, or off and on? There is a history of scaling? Do you expire keys? Especially some part of the keys while not the other?
